# Unable to pass an array as function argument in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass an array as a function argument. When I run the HTML the browser displays a blank page. Please help:) (Obviously a coding noob)

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    var list = [7, 8, 9, 4];

    document.write(list);

    pass_array(array) {
      let sum = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        sum = +list[i];
      }
      document.write(sum);
    }

    pass_array(this, list);
  </script>
</head>

</html>
```

Comment: How about `pass_array(list)` ?

Comment: Also, consider not using `document.write`?

Comment: Also, it's `+=`, not `=+`. And your parameter name is `array`, not `list`. And you need to prefix your function with `function`.

Comment: @HassanImam still displays a blank page

Comment: What debugging have you done? What does your browser devtools console show?

Comment: @evolutionxbox so use console.log instead?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen made the changes still blank page

Comment: @praveengunasekaran Surprisingly, someone in the answer below made the same changes and does not get a blank page.

Comment: It is great you are learning, and welcome to the industry, but posting a question on SO is supposed to be the last resort, when you've already put in a lot of effort in solving your own problem, and done all the research you can think of: 
 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users  If you are just starting out, start with some tutorials, guides, etc, which will also teach you how to debug.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I have been searching for a solution for a couple of hours now but somehow could not find the solution. I guess when you are starting out you really don't know what to look for. I appreciate your help:) Will keep working!

Comment: If you haven't come across using the devtools console yet, you're trying to run before you can walk :-) Look for some introductory tutorials that will teach you these basics.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace `pass_array(array)` with `function pass_array(array)` (as for function declaration), and then use `array` values inside `pass_array` function instead

`pass_array(this, list);` should have only 1 param `list` like `pass_array(list);`. In this context, `this` is not referred to your list data

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    var list = [7, 8, 9, 4];

    document.write(list);

    function pass_array(array) {
      let sum = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        sum += array[i];
      }
      document.write(sum);
    }

    pass_array(list);
  </script>
</head>

</html>
```